# Chrome ignoring height of div when page first loads or on refresh

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

For the website: http://dev.blackboxdesign.co

I am having a rather frustrating issue with Chrome.  When I first open my page with Chrome the navigation bar ignores my banner bar and pops to the top, hiding itself under the banner.  This problem fixes itself if I click on the homepage link but reappears if I refresh.  I have tried forcing a reload if Chrome was detected (but that wasn't so smart because it just made a loop).  I tried adding padding to the banner div with

```css
    padding-bottom:1px;
```

but then I get the same issue except this time the banners don't show.  I read on here someone with the same issue said it was to do with Chrome wanting image sizes.  But I am unable to define image sizes as they change with the width of the page.

HTML

```
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div id="banner_bar1"><img src="images/banner5.jpg" width="750px" height="178px" class="banner"></div>
        <div id="banner_bar2"><img src="images/banner4.jpg" width="750px" height="178px" class="banner"></div>
        <div id="banner_bar3"><img src="images/banner3.jpg" width="750px" height="178px" class="banner"></div>
        <div id="banner_bar4"><img src="images/banner2.jpg" width="750px" height="178px" class="banner"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
#banner_bar1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#313131;
}
/* repeat #banner_bar1 for 2,3,4 changing only background-color */
.slideshow {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.banner {
    display:block;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width: 750px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Oh, I forgot to mention that the problem also fixes itself on window re-size thanks to:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function Reload(){
            window.location.href = window.location.href
        }
        window.onresize = Reload;
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the margin for the banner class, but you are overriding yourself several times. The resulting property could be written as "margin: 0 auto;", replacing all the margin, margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left and margin-right rules for that class. Zero is the only length that does not require a unit in CSS because 0em == 0pt == 0px etc. With reference to your problem, do you have a link to the page so we can see what is happening? Are you applying float to the banner_bar div elements at all?

Comment: No float at all the page in question is http://dev.blackboxdesign.co

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `.banner` children of `.slideshow` have absolute position applied to them, presumably by the cycle plugin you are using, these elements do not form part of the document flow - that is to say these divs and child images do not give any height to the `.slideshow` container.

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document.  In contrast, **an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements**.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position

If you look in your developer tools of choice you will see that the `.slideshow` div has a height of zero pixels. The same would have happened if you were floating the `.banner` divs, which is why I asked. If you don't use any developer tools to inspect pages as you were building them, I suggest you consult the documentation of your favourite browser as you will find them absolutely invaluable to see what is happening "under the hood". Chrome in particular has excellent tools, with Opera's dragonfly and Mozilla (both the built in developer tools and the excellent Firebug extension) getting an exceedingly honorable mention.

As the `.banner` elements will not stretch the parent `.slideshow` container to give it height, you must manually specify a height to match the contents. In this case `215px`, note the use of unit as per my comment - simply stating `215` will not work, or at least not work correctly cross-browser.

I would suggest doing this in your external CSS file which I would edit to read as follows-

```css
#banner_bar1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #313131;
}

/* repeat #banner_bar1 for 2,3,4 changing only background-color */
.slideshow {
    height: 215px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.banner {
    display:block;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width: 750px;
    height:100%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

This also includes the updates to your margin properties I mentioned in comments.

I'm going to credit defau1t as he was pointing you in the right direction for the answer.

Comment: I found that if I removed height 100% and fixed the margins like you suggested then when I inspect the div with chrome the size shows.  It is equal to image height + 1 px

Answer (score 1):

You could add a CSS property `overflow:hidden;` to the div containing the banners,

```
.slideshow{overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: adding overflow:hidden; has the same effect as padding-bottom:1px;. . . navigation bar is shown but it hides the banner bar.

Comment: did you try adding height as well, like how you have added width 750px

Comment: All length measurements will require a unit (e.g. px, em, pt, %) in order to have any effect. The width="750" on the banner images will have no effect as units are not specified, as will the height = "178" you have specified above.

Comment: Did not know units were mandatory. . . Dreamweaver never adds them so I just assumed I didn't need them.  I have updated the units as you recommended however and it still has the same behavior.